# Change Class Backbone BootStrap

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am using backbone, bootstrap "collapse". I am trying to change the class when the button is clicked..

html

```
<button id="btnCollapse" class="btn"  type="button">
    <i id="accordionIcon-{{id}}" class="icon-down"></i>
</button>
```

js

```
CollapsePress : function(event) {

    //change the class back and forth with every click (icon-down to icon-right)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven’t given enough information for me to be sure this is correct, but try this:

```
$(event.target).find('i').toggleClass('icon-down icon-right')
```